# Mixing Australian visa types within one family

Tags: visas, australia

I intend to apply for an Australian [subclass 402 (occupational trainee stream)](http://www.immi.gov.au/visas/temporary-visa/402/occupational-trainee/) visa. It takes a bit of money (especially for collecting and translating all the necessary documents) and time to incorporate my dependants. The intended length of stay in Australia is just a bit over 2 months.

As my family is able to apply for [eVisitor](http://www.immi.gov.au/visas/visitor/651/) visas, I wondered if it is possible for them to apply separately from me?

Comment: Are they entitled to eVisitor visas based on their nationalities and what they plan to do there?

Comment: Yes, @Gagravarr, they are entitled based on their nationalities. They will be there on vacation and don't intend to study or work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why this could be a problem. If citizenship of your family allows them to enter Australia as a tourist with eVisitor visa, it should not be a problem that they get a separate one. Visiting a family member is also considered tourism.

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Unfortunately there are no case studies or examples on the immigration office website that would assure me of this.

Comment: Could it be because it is an obvious case? I mean, your family could enter with eVisitor visas separately from you, right? Just that you are "coincidentally" on the same plane does not change the situation.

Comment: Yes, @Elchin, this could be. I have not found any statements that say, that they cannot have an eVisitor visa.

Comment: I've called the Australian embassy and this answer seems correct.

Comment: Awesome! Have a safe trip!:)